# App Engine task Queue create batch of queue items and execute after every 10 second in go lang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, task-queue

I want to create batches of queue items and execute after every 10 second, due to some limitation of third party API using inside code (Third party API have 1000 API call per minute).

But i don't know how do i achieve the given requirement in App Engine with taskqueue.

Or

It is possible to create batches with taskqueue push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TaskQueue `Task`s have a `Delay time.Duration` as well as `ETA time.Time` fields which can be used to create and delay tasks. I believe you can reuse [the top example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/taskqueue/reference) but set one of the fields before calling `taskqueue.Add(c, t, "")`

Comment: There is a link to the example in my answer

Comment: For example if i get 500 request in 5 seconds, if i set 5sec delay for task, it execute all 500 request after 5 sec delay?

Comment: I see there is a second field called `ETA` as well, which defines the earliest time instead of duration. So in case, you want to be absolute, try using that. Otherwise, yes - you are right.